# How to wrap text around chemscheme schemes?

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, chemstyle, chemistry

Is `\usepackage{wrapfig}` compatible with `\usepackage{chemescheme}`?

I'm using chemescheme to number my compounds, but need to wrap the text around some schemes.

Suggestions?

e.g. (but this doesn't work):

```
\subsection{Compound Name (\compound{XXX})}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}[\sind]{.2\textwidth}
   \begin{scheme}[h]
      \schemeref{KAB35} 
      \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{XXX.eps}
   \end{scheme}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to use a floating environment like `scheme` inside a `wrapfigure`. However, the `wrapfig` package provides the means to extend the wrapping features to other floats: The `wrapfloat` environment which has a first (mandatory) argument the name of the corresponding float:

```
\begin{wrapfloat}{<float>}{...}{...}
  ...
\end{wrapfloat}
```

Both `wrapfigure` and `wraptable` are defined through this generic environment.

This means you can simply use

```
\begin{wrapfloat}{scheme}{...}{...}
  ...
\end{wrapfloat}
```

in your document.

If you plan to use this more than once it might be worth considering to define an own environment for this,`wrapscheme` say:

```
\newenvironment{wrapscheme}{\wrapfloat{scheme}}{\endwrapfloat}
```

This can then be used the same way as `wrapfigure`:

```
\begin{wrapscheme}{...}{...}
  ...
\end{wrapscheme}
```

A full example containing both variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% for dummy text:
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{wrapscheme}{\wrapfloat{scheme}}{\endwrapfloat}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{wrapfloat}{scheme}[11]{L}{4cm}
  \rule{4cm}{3cm}
  \caption{foo bar baz}
\end{wrapfloat}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{wrapscheme}[11]{L}{4cm}
  \rule{4cm}{3cm}
  \caption{foo bar baz}
\end{wrapscheme}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]